# Excel VBA how to treat value as a integer rather than as a string

Tags: string, excel, vba

I am trying to get my script to treat my value as a interger rather than a string. It is a vlookup, that gets the date from a formatted number cell. When I put the data into the sheet though, it acts as a string and not a number. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim NextProd As Long
Dim NextPC As Long
Dim NextQuant As Long
Dim NextPE As Long
Dim NextTP As Long

NextProd = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
NextPC = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
NextQuant = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
NextPE = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
NextTP = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Dim lookupRange As Range
Set lookupRange = Worksheets("Products").Range("A1:C1679")
Dim Products As Range
Set Products = Worksheets("Products").Range("A1:B1679")
Dim Description As Range
Set Descrpition = Worksheets("products").Range("A1:A1679")

ItemPrice = Application.VLookup(InvoiceProductEntry.Selectprodcutcombo.Value, lookupRange, 3, False)
ProductCode = Application.VLookup(InvoiceProductEntry.Selectprodcutcombo.Value, lookupRange, 2, False)
ProductDescription = Application.VLookup(InvoiceProductEntry.Selectprodcutcombo.Value, lookupRange, 1, False)

Totalprice = TextBox1.Value * ItemPrice

Cells(NextProd, 1) = Selectprodcutcombo.Value
Cells(NextPC, 2) = ProductCode
Cells(NextQuant, 3) = TextBox1.Text
Cells(NextPE, 4) = ItemPrice
Cells(NextTP, 5) = Totalprice

End Sub
```

How can I set the Quantity as a integer and the Price each and Total price as a currency?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Quantity` in your code, nor `Price`, nor `Total`. Please clarify.

Comment: You can probably use the `CLng`, `CInt` functions to convert string to long/integer value. For currency, you can use the `Format(_string_value_, "$0.00")` function.

Comment: Which variable is being read as a string? My thought was exactly what Mr. Zemens wrote, use `CInt` or `CLng`, depending on the specifics of the value.

Comment: `CDbl` might be a better choice than `CLng` or `CInt` for the vlookup returned to *ItemPrice* as the variable's name seems to indicate something that may contain a decimal value.

Comment: Ah sorry...Quantity is NextQuant, Price is NextPE and Total is NextTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
Cells(NextQuant, 3) = clng(TextBox1.Text)
```

And adding

```
Cells(NextPE, 4).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
Cells(NextTP, 5).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still hasn't changed. NextPE is being stored as a text when it should be a currency. I hope you can help.

Comment: Odd, what if you declare ItemPrice, ProductCode, and ProductDescription as their expected types.  You have some declared variable and some not.  I think you also have a typo in Description.  "Description" is declared but "Descrpition" (misspelled) is set.  That variable doesn't seem to be used anywhere though.

Comment: Worked out it was me being stupid. Was linking the next price to a label, which was then outputting as a string. Changed this now, so it pulls the data from a variable, which is a integer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

what kind of string is being returned and what kind of integer do you need ?

You may want either the logical number the points to the date or the date number like 20150224

If the string being returned is something like `"20150224"` the it suffices to use the `CInt()` function as in

```
my_date_int=CInt(dateString)
```

But if it is returning a string like `"2015-02-24"`  and you want a integer `20150224` you can use `Format()` as in

```
my_date_int=CInt(Format(dateString,"yyyyMMdd"))
```

please in the future be clearer about what is the input you're getting and what is the output that you desire.